# Picking objects with raycasters

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

Trying to pick some objects on click, and I'm trying to use the standard code used in every example:

```
function onMouseDown(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    canvasAbsoluteHeight = $('canvas').height();
    canvasAbsoluteWidth = $('canvas').width();

    mouseDown = true;
    mouseX = evt.offsetX == undefined ? evt.layerX : evt.offsetX;
    mouseY = evt.offsetY == undefined ? evt.layerY : evt.offsetY;

    var mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
    mouse.x = ( evt.clientX / canvasAbsoluteWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = 1 - ( evt.clientY / canvasAbsoluteHeight ) * 2;
    mouse.z = 0;

    ray = new THREE.Raycaster( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects);
    console.log('intersects', intersects);
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {


        console.log('intersects', intersects);
    }

}
```

`objects` is an array of `THREE.Object3D` which should be able to be picked.

I think it may be something connected with the camera. My `camera` is a child of `THREE.Object3D` for easier manipulation, and the parent object is not set at origin.

Other thing is that canvas is not fullscreen, which may have something with mouse position? (it is inside a div with some offset from the edges of the page).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872583/three-js-raycasting-from-a-child-camera-to-the-scene/28873205#28873205

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675875/threejs-how-to-pick-just-one-type-of-objects/28679672#28679672

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grz671u9/7/). There is Picker class that you can use. First of all you have to init this class with camera and domelement

```
Picker.init(camera,domelement)
```

and then you have to attach mesh

```
Picker.attach(mesh)
```

and after that you have to specify what do you want to do after mosedown/mouseup in Picker methods.