# THREE.JS Raycasting to a child of the camera

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I have a object (plane) that is a child of the camera so its 'fixed to the screen'.

```
                plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10), material);

                plane.position.set(0,0,-5);

                camera.add(plane);
```

On this plane I have another object which I want to move, to I am sending raycasts to the plane.

```
                if(INTERSECTED){

                handleEvent();

                raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane);

                if(intersects.length>0){

                    //what is happening here?
                    //these points are definitely not on the plane!


                    var x = intersects[0].point.x;
                    var y = intersects[0].point.y;
                    var z = intersects[0].point.z;

                    INTERSECTED.position.set(x,y,z);

                    console.log(x,y,z);

                }           
            }
```

The positions on which the rays hit the plane doesn't make any sense for me!

Please help me out, I'm stuck! 
Thanks!

Here is the fiddle:

```
jsfiddle.net/74jLjz6q/2
```

PS: I found this post, with a similar problem, where the camera was a child of another object.. I couldn't find any help for my problem there..

[THREE.js Raycasting from a child camera to the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872583/three-js-raycasting-from-a-child-camera-to-the-scene)

Comment: Try using `raycaster.intersectObject( plane,true);` The true tells the raycaster to look through the children, then `intersects[0]` should be the first object intersected

Answer (score 1):

Okey, I got it by trail and error:

It had to be the other way around (world to local).

I'm not sure if I really understood this..

So, the points are provided in world space. (..Because THREE.Raycaster always does?)
And it has to be in local space because the plane is a child of the camera.

Is that right?

(AND I had to substract the distance between the camera and the plane manually.)

```
 plane.worldToLocal( intersects[0].point );
 INTERSECTED.position.set(intersects[0].point.x,intersects[0].point.y,intersects[0].point.z-5);
```

The updated and working fiddle (The cube finally stays on the plane! :) ):

http://jsfiddle.net/74jLjz6q/9/

Comment: yeah just checked the three.js documentation (http://threejs.org/docs/?q=Raycaster#Reference/Core/Raycaster) and you're right , it always returns world coordinates, so you need to convert them to local